# Can't SSH into EC2 instance created with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano, rubber

I suppose the title is not entirely accurate.  I am able to login to an instance, but I do not see my application in any of the directories.  My sense is that I am ssh'ing into the wrong directory.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ssh into your AWS instance, you're dropped into your home directory, just as if you're running your own server.  From the terminal, try typing:

```
pwd
```

You'll likely see something like:

```
/home/ec2-user
```

Note that this is your home directory and not your application directory.  In other words, your Document Root (where the web application starts with /index.php) is likely something like /var/www/html, so try typing:

```
cd /var/www/html
ls
```

The "ls" command shows you the contents of this directory.  Here is where you'll build your web application.